# How to click on the angular-ui date picker popup Today button?

Tags: angularjs, testing, angular-ui, protractor, end-to-end

I have been trying to fill in a form using Protractor of my Angular application. Only I am having trouble to click on the `Today`-button of the angular-ui calendar popup.

I got it so far as clicking on it, but everything I tried I can't seem to be able to click on the Today button:

```
element(by.model('delivery.deliveryDate')).click();
```

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Did you try `element(by.buttonText('Today')).click()`? http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText

Comment: Aaron, yes, I tried that but that didn't work for me. Maybe I need to scroll the page a bit down so that the popup is also into view? As now it's partly get choped off.

Comment: Protractor doesn't like to click on things that aren't visible to the user, especially in responsive Angular apps. My solution in the past has been to use `browser.executeScript('scroll(0,y)')`, with `y` being the vertical pixel you want to scroll to.

Comment: Whenever I've needed to manually scroll I use the same technique @IsaacLyman described above.

Answer (score -1):

wrote a npm module for it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-angulardatepicker

here is an example usage of it .

```
it('The text box contains August 12 6:30 PM ', function() {
 browser.get('http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/');
 var p= require('protractor-angulardatePicker');
 var parentnode=element(by.css('.input-group-addon'));
 var nthnode=3;
 var dateofthemonth='12';
 var timeoftheday='6:00 PM';
 var specifictimeofthehour='6:30 PM';
 var resultinputbox=element(by.model('data.dateDropDownInput'));
 var relativetime;
 p.ptorangulardateTimePicker(parentnode, nthnode, dateofthemonth,timeoftheday,specifictimeofthehour,    relativetime, resultinputbox).then(function(result){
 console.log(result);
});
```

});

Comment: Can you add some more documenttion? also if the params are requried and so on. I would like to use that